# Android cannot deselect TextView

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I'm making a simple test app to wrap my head around reading text from TextViews in android.

My problem is: I have 2 TextViews, one for a username and one for a password field, and a button. The button calls a method that gets text from both TextViews. However, my username TextView is automatically selected when the app runs and I can type text into it, and I cannot deselect it and select the password field to write into, but I can click the button. Does anybody know what the issue might be?

Android 7.0 used for testing

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/userField"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/textView_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/textView_height"
        android:layout_above="@id/passField"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginVertical="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:background="@color/LightCoral"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:hint="@string/user"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:textAlignment="gravity"
        android:textSize="10pt"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/passField"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/textView_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/textView_height"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginVertical="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:background="@color/LightCoral"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:hint="@string/pass"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:textAlignment="gravity"
        android:textSize="10pt"
        android:visibility="visible" />


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/passField"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:width="@dimen/button_width"
        android:height="@dimen/button_height"
        android:background="@color/FireBrick"
        android:onClick="uradi"
        android:text="@string/button_tag"
        android:textColor="@color/Black" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Any reason why you don't use `EditText` instead of `TextView` ?

Comment: I'm ashamed right now. I saw in some tutorial that they used TextView. Changing TextView into EditText worked perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. Happens. I will add this as answer.Remember to mark as accepted if the answer is useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`EditText` is better widget over `TextView` for handling user input. Replace your `TextView` with `EditText`

Answer (score 0):

You should choose the controls that are suitable for the use of the sense.
The input of the username and password is generally used for EditText